# Increment a variable in Verilog for indexing a wire (using loops)

Tags: verilog

I'm new using Verilog, so I'm not even sure if I'm using syntax correctly. I need to multiply 2 input buses of 8 bits each one. I'm trying to get the result of each 8×1 in only one wire, more like concatenate the 8 results (one per 8×1 multiplication).

```
module m8bit(
    input reg[7:0]A, 
    input reg[7:0]B);
wire [63:0] P;

genvar i,j;
integer k=0;

for(i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin
    for(j=0; j<8; j=j+1)begin
         P[k]=(A[i])*(B[j]);
         k<=k+1;
    end
end
```

As you can see I used genvar `i` and `j` to iterate the digits of the bus, but as I need o get all the results in one wire `[63:0]P`, I can't use `i` or `j` (they reset when the loop restarts). When I try to compile, I get these errors:

```
** Error: (vlog-13069) mult8bit.v(21): near "[": syntax error, unexpected '['.

** Error:mult8bit.v(21): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'P'.   
Is there a missing '::'?
```

Comment: Note: It's not the complete code nor I'm usign P as output because I need to keep working with it, could this be the problem? I'm just making sure that part is ok.

Comment: `P[k]=(A[i])*(B[j]);` is line 21

Answer (score 0):

few things.

1. when you say `A[i] * B[j]`, every array selector selects a single bit from your inputs. The results get assigned to a single bit of `P[k]`. I do not think that this is what you really wanted. So, work on your declarations of the variables first.
2. all actions in verilog only possible inside `procedural` blocks, e.g. `always` block, or as a result of continuous assignment, i.e. `assign` statement. So, in your case you need to use `assign` for `P` (because `P` is a **wire**): `assign P[k] = A[i]* B[j]`;
3. since you used `generate` blocks with `genvars` to generate verilog statements, you cannot use `k` this way. You cannot modify a variable in a `generate` block. Verilog syntax also does not allow you having free-standing assignments to genvars. But you can use an expression in the index, i.e. `P[i * 8 + j]`, which is probably the easiest way.

So, here is an example which is compilable:

```
module m8bit(
  input reg[7:0]A[8], 
  input reg[7:0]B[8],
  output wire [16:0] P[64]);

genvar i,j;

for(i=0; i<8; i=i+1) begin
    for(j=0; j<8; j=j+1)begin
      assign P[i * 8 + j]=(A[i])*(B[j]);
    end
end 

endmodule
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. About the first point, I do need them all in a single array, bit by bit, because I need to use full adders in order to get the final answer, (we're practicing instances so the point it's not to get the direct answer, we need to get it using wallace tree model but in a very modular way).

I'm not so used to use `always`, but I'm checking it later on in the code, I'll keep you updated, thanks again.

Comment: verilog is not a regular programming language and many concepts will not be familiar to a generic language programmer. You need to go through a verilog tutorial and available examples. Why would you use multiplication `*` for an adder?

Comment: I've noticed that. I'm not explaining this clearly I think; we need to make a 8 by 8 multiplier using wallace tree model, that means we need to consider row by row of answers (like in a normal multiplication) and then add them instancing half and full adders, I thought at first using one wire for all rows would be the easiest way for keeping the order while instancing, but then I looked for some alternatives  (like using bidimensional wires) when I noticed the syntax was wrong but I didn't know why it was wrong, that's why I posted this